# Is there something like Vector3 for integers in Dart?

Tags: dart

In the `vector_math_64` library we have the [Vector3](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/vector_math_64/Vector3-class.html) class. Which contains coordinates x, y and z as doubles. Is there something similar for integers?

I could implement my own class:

```
class Coordinates {
  int x, y, z;

  Coordinate(this.x, this.y, this.z);
}
```

But I don't want to lose all those valuable functions like `distanceTo`...